# c debug problem, free method

Tags: c, debugging, free

I have the problem in C program:

```
char *str = (char *) malloc(20);
strcpy_s(str, 10, "abcdefghij");

//here I change one byte before str and one byte after
*((int*)str-1) = 10;
*((int*)(str+20)) = 10;

//and it stops on the..

free(str);
```

line during the debug
what's wrong?

The part with overwriting not allocated memory is the part of the task. I know that usually it's not correct, but in this context it is the part of the task.

Comment: Orthogonal to your question, but [don't cast `malloc` in C](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).  It can hide bugs.

Comment: If you write outside of the buffer you've allocated with malloc() then what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allowed to write to `str+20` because you only requested 20 bytes, so `str+19` is the last byte you own. And the same goes for `str-1`.

Comment: I know, but this is exactly what I need - to overwrite the byte AFTER the sequence of allocated bytes. It shouldn't affect the free method, I suppose

Comment: @Sergey, so request this memory by using `malloc`! You're not allowed to access memory you did not request.

Comment: @Sergey: attempting to overwrite the byte AFTER the sequence technically results in Undefned Behavior. It can crash, or do whatever else it wants. Just don't do it

Comment: @Sergey: why do you think you need to write outside of the area you allocated? What are you trying to accomplish? Whatever you're trying to do, you need to find a different way to do it (the most obvious would be a replacement for malloc that increases the allocation size and returns an incremented pointer).

Comment: is it possible to allocate memory relative to the given pointer?

Comment: @Sergey No. How do you know that memory is not used by someone else? You can never know.

Answer (score 5):

Why on earth would you think that you have the right to change anything located at `str-1`? You don't :)

It appears you have yet another problem, which, because of the vividness of the first one went past my attention. the addresses you may acces vary from `str + 0` to `str + 19`. `str + 20` is out of your realm :)

Both these things result in what's called [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Which means you can't get surprised at ***any*** behavior! Including failing `free`, debugger crash, or whatever else

Answer (score 4):

Writing to memory outside what you allocated gives undefined behavior.

In this particular case, we can guess that the heap manager *probably* has some book-keeping information about each block of memory stored just before the memory that it hands to you. When you write to the byte before your allocated block, you're overwriting some part of that, so it can no longer free the block correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`*((int*)str-1)` is often used to store the length of the allocated space, so that `free` knows how much byte to free...

Comment: +1 Great reply! This directly answers the question why `free` fails.

Comment: I checked for this byte, it's not the size

Comment: I use visual studio 2010, maybe different compilers do it differently?

Comment: @Sergey No matter what compiler you're using and no matter what this memory is used for, **you must never access memory that you did not request** (well, unless you're writing malicious software and you know very well what you are doing).

Comment: @Sergey, yes of course different compilers do it differently. There can be other information stored there. Remark also that the allocated size could be different than the one requested (could be larger).